# How do I deal with nested objects when not using an ORM?

Tags: java, jdbc, orm

I'm making the switch away from ORMs in Java and I was wondering what was the best way of dealing with many-to-one and many-to-one relationships in a non-ORM setting.

In my `Customer.java` class I have:

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private Date dob;
//About 10 more fields
private List<Pet> pets;
```

In `Pet.java` I have:

```
private String id;
private String name;
private Customer owner;
```

My database table for Pet looks like this

```
id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
owner_id BIGSERIAL REFERENCES...
```

Now I realize that if I run a query that joins the two tables, I get a "flat" data structure returned which contains the fields for both `Customer` and `Pet` as well as any foreign keys. What is the common/most efficient way to treat the data in this scenario?

a. Rebuild the object graph manually by calling `customer.setName(resultSet.getString(("name"))`...?
b. Use the returned data as is by converting it to a `Map<String, Object>`?

The data flow is: Data is read from the database -> rendered to JSON for use by an AngularJS front end -> modified data is sent back to the server for validation -> domain logic applied -> saved to database.

Comment: If column `id` of table `Pet` is `BIGSERIAL`, why is field `id` a `String`? It should be a `long`. Also, table `Pet` should *not* have two columns of type `BIGSERIAL`.

Comment: It's just for illustrative purposes. Actual schema is a lot more sane and consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read both Customer and Pet in a single query for better performance, you can do something like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
String sql = "SELECT c.id AS cust_id" +
                  ", c.name AS cust_name" +
                  ", c.dob AS cust_dob" +
                  ", p.id AS pet_id" +
                  ", p.name AS pet_name" +
              " FROM Customer c" +
              " LEFT JOIN Pet p ON p.owner_id = c.id" +
             " WHERE c.name LIKE ?" +
             " ORDER BY c.id";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "%DOE%");
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        Customer customer = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            long cust_id = rs.getLong("cust_id");
            if (customer == null || customer.getId() != cust_id) {
                customer = new Customer();
                customer.setId(cust_id);
                customer.setName(rs.getString("cust_name"));
                customer.setDob(rs.getDate("cust_dob"));
                customers.add(customer);
            }
            long pet_id = rs.getLong("pet_id");
            if (pet_id != 0) {
                Pet pet = new Pet();
                pet.setId(pet_id);
                pet.setName(rs.getString("pet_name"));
                pet.setOwner(customer);
                customer.addPet(pet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After a couple days searching around online, I've concluded that while this seems to be the long way (and the way I was most hoping to get away from) it seems to be the way everyone else is doing it. Manual object-relational mapping is a bit tedious, but I guess it's necessary sometimes.

Marking this as accepted.

Comment: Manually mapping to object *is* tedious, which is why ORMs were invented, to do it for you. If you don't want an ORM to map columns to fields for you, then you have to do it yourself. I mean, it's called ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) for a reason.

Comment: If only they didn't come with the SQL generation stuff or the need for external XML configuration files, I'd use them more often.

Comment: So you're after manual SQL with automatic `ResultSet` to Object mapping? I assume that's what you mean by not wanting "the SQL generation stuff". As for the XML part, most ORMs support annotations now.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm after. I've started working on a little helper class that does just this.

Answer (score 1):

The best option at this time are:

1. Spring JDBC (it has convenience of ORM like bean to object mapping etc.)
2. iBatis (allows to write SQL queries manually although it is ORM but a thin layer)
3. Write your own DAO layer implementation.

In all these cases you write your own sql queries and mostly they will result in join queries. By the way the example you have given are not nested objects.

Comment: What about tools like Sql2o? Have you used it or anything like it?

Comment: I have not used it but by looking at it it seems to be a small version of criteria query. By the way I prefer Spring JDBC due to its support for most of the existing databases, Dependency Injection (loose coupling) and due to the fact that it has Unchecked exceptions and very clear exception hierarchy. You can clearly tell what exact SQLException has occurred.